# C# 8 project generate .g.cs in c# 9?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-8.0, c#-9.0, visual-studio-2022

This morning I had an issue with my VS 2019 so I did update to to latest version and it fixed the issue. As the installer also proposed to install VS 2022 preview I also did it.
Since I did it (is it related I don't know) I have 29 errors "Feature 'target-typed object creation' is not available in C# 8.0. Please use language version 9.0 or greater." in my project.
The code who cause the error is:
`Dictionary<string, object> args = new();`
but this happen in the .g.cs ie: in _layout.cshtml.g.cs but of course it is a generated file and I didn't have write this line.

I am stuck in .net core 3.1 so I cannot really activate c# 9. It is as if the precompilation is done in c# 9 but after that the compilation is done in c# 8... really weird...

If it can help I have uploaded the build output in diagnostic mode here: https://spaces.hightail.com/space/XOQxYSGqnS

Comment: You used a preview version of Visual Studio. Problems are *expected* to happen. You can target C# 9 in a .NET Core 3.1 but some features that require runtime support won't be available.

Comment: Ok but it also happens in VS2019 not only in VS2022

Comment: Btw yes if I activate the C#9 on this project I am able to bypass the issue but I would like to stay in c#8 for the moment to stay at the same version as the other team members...

Comment: Post a minimal sample that reproduces the problem in the question itself, not external links that take ages to open. Installing VS 2022 also updates the installed MSBUILD version and any generators. The latest tool version will be used each time. Try creating a new MVC project from the command-line, targeting .NET Core 3.1 and add just enough code to reproduce the problem. If you don't can't reproduce the proble, it's probably caused by the MSBUILD version used by VS. You can change that from Properties or by creating a `global.json` file in the roof of your solution.

Comment: I have tried to add a global.json like this (not sure if that is correct) but it doesn't help.
```{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.100",
    "allowPrerelease": false
  }
}```